# Wait for then() to finish

Tags: node.js

I have been having a problem waiting for one part of my code to finish for me to run the other part,
How can part 1 finish before part 2?

```
var uidArray = [];
// Part 1
admin.auth().listUsers(1000).then(result => {
    result.users.forEach(userRecord => {
        uidArray.push(userRecord.uid);
        console.log("pushing to uid array user " + userRecord.uid);
    });
    return;
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error listing users:" + error);
});
uidArray.forEach(uid => {
    // Part 2 of the code
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why does "part 2" need to be outside of the `.then`?

Comment: Read about promises in Javascript and I am pretty sure someone will flag this as a duplicate question.

Comment: make your changes to uidArray in the first .then() or add a second .then() before the first one and the .catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async-await for better data manipulation. However, forEach is by default asynchronous it can't wait until for each completes you can use below using async-await with try-catch block.

```
try{
    var uidArray = [];
    const result = await admin.auth().listUsers(1000);
    for(const userRecord of result.users) {
        uidArray.push(userRecord.uid);
        console.log("pushing to uid array user " + userRecord.uid);
    }
    uidArray.forEach(uid => {
        // Part 2 of the code
    });
} catch(err) {
console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var uidArray = [];
// Part 1
admin.auth().listUsers(1000).then(result => {
    result.users.forEach(userRecord => {
        uidArray.push(userRecord.uid);
        console.log("pushing to uid array user " + userRecord.uid);
    });
    return;
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error listing users:" + error);
}).then(()=>{
    uidArray.forEach(uid => {
        // Part 2 of the code
    });
});
```

The key here is that after you start a promise, you can keep `then`ing off it.  Ideally you should also return a promise after each step, but it's not required.

This link has more information

https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code using **`async-await`** as it is good for data manipulation.i prefer `for loop` instead using `forEach`.

```
async function test(){
  try{

     let result = await admin.auth().listUsers(1000);

     let usersArray = result.users;

     var uidArray = usersArray.map(function(item) { return item.uid; });

    // here you can loop through uidArrar either for or forEach whatever you want

     for(let i =0 ; i< uidArray.length; i++){

        // your code to be executed in second part
     }

   } catch (e) {
    //error
   }
}
test()
```